# use unique URL for localhost and server

Tags: php, wordpress, html, url

I use `ampps` for `localhost`developments. I need to find a way that I should be able to use same URL on klocalhost and in server.

Ex :-

`localhost` - xyz.com

`server` - xyz.com

**Current Issue**

I had to add `www`in option_value of `wordpress` for home and `siteurl` option on server repository just to differ local site from live site. When I pull changes from server to localhost, it comes with "www". I dont want to always make changes to url system.

For this purpose, I need unique URL. **I must not need to look after www and non www part.**

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Technically www is a sub domain. So your website should be called without the www part. You can use apache or any other web server to redirect all www traffic to be directed to the main domain. So links inside pages could be without www without any problem.

Comment: you can create a virtual host in localhost. it lets you create custom url (ex- xyz.com  to localhost/yoursite).

Answer (score 0):

**Create the Virtual Host**

First, you need to navigate to C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra or wherever your XAMPP (in this case ampps) files are located. We need to locate `apache` folder anyway. Then edit `httpd-vhosts.conf` with any text editor.Something like *Notepad++* or *sublime text*. Even simply using notepad is okay.

Insert the following code at the end of the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/your_project"
ServerName xyz.com
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/your_project">
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

- VirtualHost: Most web servers use port 80 as their default port. However, you can change the port to 8080, 8081 etc.
- DocumentRoot: The folder where files of a site will exist. In our case, the folder name is “WordPress”.
- ServerName: It is the URL for our virtual host.
- Directory: It is the directory of our virtual host.

Now open notepad/ your text editor as Administrator. go to this location,

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

open the file named `hosts` insert this line at the end.

```
127.0.0.1      xyz.com
```

Now restart `apache`. Now you'll be able to access your local site with given virtual host name.